# Test convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty{(\ln{n})^{-n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty{(\ln{n})^{-n}}$$
How can I test convergence for this sum? I can get a conclusion with Ratio test but limit is hard. With Cauchy condension test I cant come to a conclusion.

Comment: Should the series begin at $n=2$?

Answer (score 2):

$\ln n$ is greater than $\ln 2$, so the sum is bounded by a geometric series.

Comment: This argument ensures that the root test limit will be less than $1$.  So one might try the root test directly...

Comment: @Professor Clark: That's also right. I just wanted to give a different approach.